# Merge without proc sorting in SAS

Tags: sorting, merge, sas

I have two similar data table that look like the following:

```
Data 1:                        Data 2: 
categorical     value          categorical     value
Sex                            Sex    
 Male             2             Male             3
 Female           3             Female           1     
Weight                         Weight
 Mean             50            Mean             49 
 Median           53            Median           51
```

I would like to merge them without having to proc sort. How can I do so? I know classically, I would have to proc sort by categorical, and then merge by categorical but I don't want an alphabetized categorical category.

```
Desired output:                     
categorical     value          value2
Sex                               
 Male             2              3
 Female           3              1     
Weight                        
 Mean             50             49 
 Median           53             51
```

Comment: Use `left` joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's one to one, each line with each line, just omit the BY statement in a data step merge.

```
data want;
 merge t1 t2 (rename=value=new_value);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know if this something on my end, but when I merge the 'value' column disappears and I only have the 'value2' column.

Comment: You do need to rename one of the value columns. If they have the same name it will overwrite the variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sql;
    create table dataMerged as
    select data1.categorical, data1.value, data2.value as value2
    from data1 LFET JOIN data2
    on data1.categorical = data2.categorical;
quit;
```